# Is there any possible way to analyse instagram and facebook comments?

Tags: r, excel, facebook, instagram, facebook-comments

i currently work at a scientific project that tries to analyze the comment section of a particular posting both in instagram and facebook and later compare the results. Therefore i would like to ask if there is a handy way to extract the comments and sort them by their likes?

Thanks!

Comment: You will not be able to access any data that the user specifically granted you permission to see. Also I'm pretty sure Facebook would not grant you permission to even ask for the permissions for doing research. To do research you should use https://research.fb.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should be possible.  Have you ever worked with the Facebook and Instagram Graph APIs before?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks

It looks like you might be able to find out a way to get comments on Instagram though the documentation is a big vague from what I could find.  At the very least you can get the number of comments and likes on a post, but I'm not clear on whether you can load the individual comments or likes on comments.  Might be worth some experimentation.  Maybe some kind of phrasing similar to `media{comments{like_count}}`?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery#getting-basic-metrics-on-media

It looks like you can do it pretty easily on Facebook at though.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/comment

R has a number of good sorting algorithms you can use.  I think the big challenge here is figuring out how to get the API set up and accessing the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I researched some time myself and found out, that we need to use those APIs but neither i nor my research team did work with it before. Our research tries to compare the top decile of the most liked comments both on FB and insta on a specific post. Therefore we would need the individual comments and the number of likes on them in order to sort them and calculate the top decile.